Vitest not properly interpreting TypeScript
I have the following setup test:
import {  describe, it } from "vitest";
import { init, initServer } from "../src";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

describe("#setup", () => {
  it("should initialize the server", async () => {
    await init(await initServer() as string);
  });
});

Note that cannot use beforeEach of any other before methods because it can only run once on the test command.
However, when I run it I get an error:
[!] RollupError: src/index.ts (22:23): Expected ',', got ':' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
src/index.ts (22:23)
20:  * @async
21:  */
22: const init = async (url: string, password?: string) => {
                           ^
23:   const response = await fetch(url);
RollupError: Expected ',', got ':'

I see no reason why this would throw an error is it is valid TS. Here is my Vite config:
import {defineConfig} from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    watch: {
      ignored: ["node_modules", "dist"]
    }
  },
  test: {
    globalSetup: "tests/setup.spec.ts"
  }
});


Vitest workspace:
import { defineWorkspace } from "vitest/config";

export default defineWorkspace([
    {
    extends: "vite.config.ts",
    test: {
        include: ["tests/setup.spec.ts"],
        name: "setup",
        environment: "node" 
    }
}])

Rollup config:
import serve from "rollup-plugin-serve";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import copy from "rollup-plugin-copy";

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        dir: "dist",
        format: "es"
      }
    ],

    inlineDynamicImports: true,
    presserveModules: true,
    plugins: [
      serve({contentBase: "dist"}),
      typescript(),
      copy({targets: [{src: "src/server/init.sh", dest: "dist"}]})
    ],
    external: ["express"]
  }
];



typescript support is added in your rollup config, I thought that was only used when creating the prod package (so not when running tests)

the order of the plugins in rollup is important, so you should start by typescript() plugin then serving using serve() plugin
    plugins: [
      typescript(),
      serve({contentBase: "dist"}),
      copy({targets: [{src: "src/server/init.sh", dest: "dist"}]})
    ],

I don't know what file you are copying using copy but if it's important for the server or the build, then don't forget that the order is important
